# “Lower-case” is to “upper-case” as what is to “capital”?

Tags: word-request, adjectives, synonyms, antonyms

For describing letters, what word is to “capital” as “lower-case” is to “upper-case”?

I am looking for an adjective which is a synonym of “lower-case”.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are looking for **non-capital** or **minuscule**.

When talking about letter case, there are majuscule letters (depending of the context they can be capital, caps, upper-case, etc) and minuscule letters (non-capital, lower-case)

from NOAD:

> **minuscule** (*adj*.) of or in lowercase letters, as distinct from capitals or uncials.

Comment: By "depending of the context they can be capital, caps, upper-case, etc", you mean they are not completely same?

Comment: They are the same, but what I meant is that in orthography you called them as **"capital"** letters, but in that context you probably can't refer them as **"caps"**, since the first one is part of the proper jargon of the english language. **"caps"** is a term that you probably use in a informal conversation, or an a computer science problem.

BTW: I'm not a native speaker, neither a literati. This is only my humble opinion :)

Answer (score 3):

This might sound a little too simple or silly, but in explaining to kids, we'll just use the word 'small'.

"Kids, write the 'T' as capital and the rest of the word in small letters."

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia says: "upper case (also uppercase, capital letters, capitals, caps, large letters, or more formally majuscule) and smaller lower case (also lowercase, small letters, or more formally minuscule)"